# Boost.Asio: Segmentation fault when sending too big message

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, segmentation-fault

My program saves some internal logs to a .txt file. 
If you connect to it via TCP (SSL encrypted), the program will send the contents of the log file.

This is the code that is sending the data:

```
void NIUserSession::write(std::string message)
{
    std::cout << "Writing message" << std::endl;
    message.append("<EOF>");
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::asio::async_write(this->socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message),
                       boost::asio::transfer_all(), boost::bind(&NIUserSession::writeHandler,
                                                                this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred()));
}

void NIUserSession::writeHandler(const boost::system::error_code &error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    std::cout << "Write Handler" << std::endl;
    if(error)
    {
        std::cout << "Write handler error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
        this->disconnect();
    }
}
```

So `NIUserSession::write` gets passed the logfile contents as string.

If the program is not running for a very long time the logfile is short and everything works fine. However, if it runs for a while and the log file gets longer and longer, the program will receive a `SIGSEGV` when it tries to send the data. This is the gdb log:

```
Writing message

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff4fe1700 (LWP 21047)]
__memcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:33
33      ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) where
#0  __memcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:33
#1  0x00007ffff7998454 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#2  0x00007ffff79985c3 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#3  0x00000000004b7eca in boost::asio::ssl::detail::io_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::ssl::detail::write_op<boost::asio::const_buffers_1>, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >, boost::asio::const_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, NIUserSession, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<NIUserSession*>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> > > > >::operator()(boost::system::error_code, unsigned long, int) ()
#4  0x00000000004b8bf8 in boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >, boost::asio::const_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, NIUserSession, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<NIUserSession*>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> > > >::operator()(boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long, int) ()
#5  0x00000000004b7e6c in boost::asio::ssl::detail::io_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::ssl::detail::write_op<boost::asio::const_buffers_1>, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >, boost::asio::const_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, NIUserSession, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<NIUserSession*>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> > > > >::operator()(boost::system::error_code, unsigned long, int) ()
#6  0x00000000004b965c in boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_send_op<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::ssl::detail::io_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::ssl::detail::write_op<boost::asio::const_buffers_1>, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >, boost::asio::const_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, NIUserSession, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<NIUserSession*>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> > > > > > >::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service*, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) ()
#7  0x00000000004add59 in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service*, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) ()
#8  0x00000000004ad911 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&) ()
#9  0x00000000004a9c1f in NetInterface::init() ()
#10 0x00007ffff641aa60 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#11 0x00007ffff566e184 in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff4fe1700) at pthread_create.c:312
#12 0x00007ffff5b8237d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
```

I don't understand why it is happening. Do I maybe have to give a size to `boost::asio::buffer`?

Also, `io_service::run()` is running in its own detached thread. Could this be a problem?

Comment: valgrind can give the line number where the fault happens, did you try it?

Comment: Well I think is has to be somewhere deep in Boost.Asio, because I use `async_write`. The `write`-function gets called, but the `writeHandler` is never reached. But I can still try it.

Comment: Very strange, with valgrind I do not receive a sigsegv...

Comment: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.crashes  §4.4

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it with memcheck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the common issue with asio usage. You are sending buffer using `boost::asio::buffer(message)`, which does not copy the data. It just creating a reference for the data and you are responsible for this object (your `message`) lifetime until operation ends. But when you exit function `NIUserSession::write` all stack variables are destroyed, including your `message`.

To fix this you should place your data into a object with longer lifetime, for example into **shared_ptr**. Valid example can be something like this:

```
void NIUserSession::write(std::string &message_orig)
{
    std::cout << "Writing message" << std::endl;

    std::shared_ptr message = std::make_shared<std::string>( message_orig );
    message->append("<EOF>");
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::asio::async_write(this->socket_, boost::asio::buffer(*message),
        boost::asio::transfer_all(), boost::bind(&NIUserSession::writeHandler,
               this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
               boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred(),
               message /* <- capture it into callback to guarantee lifetime */
               ));
}
```